# Why is my TCP client sending chineese characters?

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, tcp, buffer

So I am working on a very simple project, a client that connects to a premade server that can recieve data.
I am trying to send a buffer but when it revieves the buffer it gets chinese chartacters even though I am trying to send "Hello World!"

How do i properly encode my buffer so that when the server recieves it, it doesnt recieve chinese characters?

Also.. The client freezes after sending something, why is that?

[Visual representation showing what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYzcg.png)

```
const string IP = "127.0.0.1";
        const int port = 12345;
        TcpClient Client = new TcpClient();

        public Form1()
        {
            Client.NoDelay = true;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SendMessage()
        {
            //Create the message we are going to send.
            string texttoSend = DateTime.Now.ToString();

            //Create a network stream to get all the data that comes and goes through the client.
            NetworkStream nwStream = Client.GetStream();

            //Convert out string message to a byteArray because we will send it as a buffer later.
            byte[] bytesToSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(texttoSend);

            //Write out to the console what we are sending.
            Console.WriteLine("Sending: " + texttoSend);

            //Use the networkstream to send the byteArray we just declared above, start at the offset of zero, and the size of the packet we are sending is the size of the messages length.
            nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);

            //Recieve the bytes that are coming from the other end (server) through the client and store them in an array.
            byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[Client.ReceiveBufferSize];

            //read the bytes, starting from the offset 0, and the size is what ever the client has recieved.
            int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, Client.ReceiveBufferSize);

            //Decode the bytes we just recieved using the Encoding.ASCII.GetString function and give it the correct parameters
            //1. What it should decode
            //2. Starting to decode from what offset
            //3. How much do we want to decode?
            Console.WriteLine("Recieved: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead));
            Console.ReadLine();

            //Close the client so we're not leaving it open for people to eavesdrop.
            Client.Close();
        }

        private async Task Connect()
        {

            try
            {
                await Client.ConnectAsync(IP, port);
                btnConnect.BackColor = Color.Green;
                btnConnect.Text = "Connected.";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Server refused the connection.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                Debug.Print(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        private async void btnConnect_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Connect();
        }

        private void btnSendAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendMessage();
        }
```

Comment: TCP doesn't care about languages let alone _Chinese_.  It just sends _bytes_.  The problem is elsewhere

Comment: Any reason why you appear to be sending to yourself?  where is the server code?

Comment: The server is a custom made server given to us by the school, I can not access the source code nor have the privilage of getting to it.

Comment: @MickyD I only have access to the port and IP its running on, I start it on my PC obviously.

Comment: Please don't deface your question. By doing this you are essentially rendering all the help, efforts and answers posted by the volunteers of this site as obsolete, and this isn't fair to them at all.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the server is expecting requests using ASCII encoding? Most likely the issue you are seeing is a mismatch in encodings between server and client. NET uses UTF8 by default.

You can also simplify some of your code by using [StreamReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx) and [StreamWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
private void SendMessage()
{
    //---data to send to the server---
    string textToSend = DateTime.Now.ToString();

    NetworkStream nwStream = Client.GetStream();

    //---send the text---
    Console.WriteLine("Sending : " + textToSend);
    using (StreamWriter nwsWriter = new StreamWriter(nwStream, Encoding.ASCII))
    {
        nwsWriter.Write(textToSend);
    }

    //---read back the text---
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(nwStream, Encoding.ASCII))
    {
        string responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Debug.Print("Received : " + responseText);
    }

    Client.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the server is talking Unicode or a different encoding to your application.

I did a quick version similar to yours but with decoding on the "server" as unicode and get some chinese characters.

http://share.linqpad.net/4bf7ag.linq

Sending: 20/01/2018 12:33:59 PM

Received: 〲〯⼱〲㠱ㄠ㨲㌳㔺‹䵐

```
//Create the message we are going to send.
string texttoSend = DateTime.Now.ToString();

//Create a network stream to get all the data that com
MemoryStream nwStream = new MemoryStream();

//Convert out string message to a byteArray because we
byte[] bytesToSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(texttoSen

//Write out to the console what we are sending.
Console.WriteLine("Sending: " + texttoSend);

//Use the networkstream to send the byteArray we just 
nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);

Encoding.Unicode.GetString(nwStream.ToArray()).Dump();
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed the encoding on the buffer to Unicode!

```
byte[] bytesToSend = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(texttoSend);
```

Comment: Fine but you shouldn't be guessing. There is no text but encoded text. If a server expects text, its operators must communicate to you which single encoding it accepts or provide you with a way to communicate to it which encoding you chose to use (which obviously must be within their capabilities—recurse on the requirement for communication).